# How to convert time.time from local to UTC while mapped to the database?

Tags: oracle, go, sqlx

I have the example code below. I am using sqlx, [null.v4](https://github.com/guregu/null) and oracle database where the time is stored in local time. I want to know if there is a way to convert the local time to UTC while reading the time from the database. Ideally, i do not want to do the conversion post query since the number of fields of type time are a lot.

```
type Person struct {

     ScheduledTime null.Time `db:"Scheduled_Time" json:"scheduledTime"`
}
```

Comment: Wrap each column in the query with `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(...)` function? Or do you rey on `sqlx` to generate the query?

Comment: I am relying on sqlx to generate the query and i get the error "missing destination name SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(columnname)" when i try this in the query string i am passing to sqlx

Comment: Try aliasing it to 'Scheduled_Time' using 'SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(columnname) AS Scheduled_Time'

Answer (score 1):

i have a same problem before so this is you can try.

> you can insert `now()` on your query

> time.parse(format, {your dateTime string})
> they have 2 return data.
> example

```
format := "2000-02-02 02:02:02"
t, err := time.Parse(format, {yourDate})
```

if you can't you can alternative with `substring` before and get your small data